# How authorize user can land directly on site's private page?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Currently i am using LR 6.1.2 CE where we use site as a group page. I want when authorize user click on the group name, it must landed directly on site's private page. Currently its landing
on group's public page!

Comment: can you give more information where exactly user is clicking,? Is it your custom portlet or liferay's portlet?

Comment: @PankajKathiriya there is a custom dropdown list for groups.
Can we achieve this task through control panel?

Comment: There is a custom landing page hook in liferay app store, you can have alook on that.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using direct page URL**

Page URL has some indication about public or private page, i.e. all public page URLs starts with "/web", followed by "/" and then followed by "/". Whereas private page URL starts with "/group" and rest are same as public page.

If you would like to land on a private page of a particular site, then you can place private page URL that starts with "/group".

**If you are using domain names mapped to site pages**

Also, If you are using domain names for your site, then you can configure different domain for public pages & private pages. i.e. www.mydomain1.com or public page and www.mydomain2.com for private pages.

You may take a look into Control Panel -> Site Settings -> Site URL -> Virtual Hosts